# Making a .py into a standalone executable with easygui and pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, portability, easygui

I would be willing to use only pygame, but using easygui makes it a lot easier to select levels. I am running ubuntu, but if neccesarry I have access to a windows machine. My main purpose is to make it easier for my non-program savvy friends to play my games. They are all either mac or windows people, so a EASY solution for either or both that can incorporate both of my modules would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at these

- `py2app` - http://wiki.python.org/moin/MacPython/py2app
- `py2exe` - http://www.py2exe.org/

Both of these can create standalone executable files for your app. They take care packaging all the dependencies into the binary so you don't have to worry about missing libraries.